# Are certain flagged comments automatically removed?

Tags: discussion

It has happened at least 4 times that I flagged comments as `too chatty` and the were instantly removed.

Usually when I flag comments, they stay there with a flag sign next to them. But in these 4 instances they were instantly removed, without refreshing the webpage.

The latest instance was a comment posted to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18395633/how-to-hide-show-uiview-with-animation-in-iphone/18395979#18395979).

Comment: Flagging can *always* delete comments automatically, given enough comment flags. How many flags depends on the content; certain keywords lower the flagging threshold, sometimes all the way down to 1 (so only *your flag* deletes the comment).

Comment: Also see [Who has the power to delete a comment?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/99812) over on Meta.SE.

Comment: Thanks a bunch martin. I was pretty sure it must have been answered, but I failed to find the answer you pointed to. :)